# How to get a node from xml not knowing its level in flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

My question is, that how can I get the node in witch I want to insert:

I.e

```
    <folder id="1">
          <folder id="4">
               <folder id="5"></folder>
          </folder>
    </folder>
    <folder id="2">
          <file id="4"/>
    </folder>
    <folder id="3">
    </folder>
```

I want to get folder with id = 4, but that can be on any level.

If folders couldn't contain one another than it would be like this myNode = xml.folder.(@id == 4).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `..` operator, it looks for all the nodes with given name and it doesn't matter how deep they are. For example `xml..folder`
will find all the `<folder/>`  nodes in your XML. So what you're trying to do will be `myNode = xml..folder.(@id == 4)`.