# How to get a node from xml not knowing its level in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

We have tree structure like this:

```xml
<Tree>
   <child1>
         <child2>
         <child2>
   </child1>
</Tree>
```

Here the `child2` can be at any level.  Is there any way we can access `child2` without knowing the hierarchy?

**Thanks for all answer..is there any way in Castor?as we are using Castor for marshalling and unmarshilling**

Here is a similar type of question: [How to get a node from xml not knowing its level in flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396895/how-to-get-a-node-from-xml-not-knowing-its-level-in-flex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using XPath, you could do it something like this:

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList child2Nodes= (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//child2", doc, 
    XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Where doc is your org.w3c.dom.Document class.

Answer (score 2):

Use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/) to get the nodes.
//child2 - to get the list of all "child2" elements

Answer (score 1):

If you can use SAX parser than it is easy here your ContentHandler

```
public class CH extends DefaultHandler
{
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
      if (qName.equals("child2"))
      {
          // here you go do what you need here with the attributes 
      }
    }
}
```

pass it to parser and you are done

like

```
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class TestParse {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      XMLReader parser = 
          org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();

      // Create a new instance and register it with the parser
      ContentHandler contentHandler = new CH();
      parser.setContentHandler(contentHandler);

      parser.parse("foo.xml"); // see javadoc you can give it a string or stream 
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```